# Which Stack Exchange site to use for dynamic app development tool questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, web

We are building a dynamic app development platform. Its approaches are directly aligned with the way apps are built using code though it's a complete drag and drop and no code system.

Though developers will relate to the approach instantly, anyone can use the system after going through a couple of hours of video.

My question is which community among the Stack Exchange sites is good for forging Q & A around the tool, and how/what is the process for creating a dedicated tag for it ?

E.g. a developer is creating a specific form using the system and encounters a challenging situation and wants to ask how to implement the specific needed feature. We would like such developers to use SE to ask their qustions. Which SE site should we use for a product such as this?

Comment: "what is the process for creating a dedicated tag for it" > Create a first question. If you have enough reputation you can add a non-existing tag to it, which will create the tag.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for clarifying the tag part. I do not understand why this question would be marked as a duplicate of the one that you pointed to. The thread you identified has a very generic outline and description for what type goes where and covers around 20 odd silo descriptions where as my question is pin pointed and specifies the category of questions expected for our product. I sincerely believe my question is far specific then the one you have pointed. Can other reviewers review this and give an opinion please ? And I don't think its a discussion since its a pin pointed question.

Comment: The duplicate looks correct to me. Your users can use it as a guide to determine where they should ask their question. There is no reason why all questions about your product should be on the same site.

Comment: So you're building a tool for people entirely new to programming? Please be **very** careful before you send your users to Stack Overflow. At the very least, make it clear to them that if they're going to ask things on SO, they should show what they have tried. Anything less is a recipe for drama.

Comment: @PatrickHofman can you help me delete / archive this question ?

Answer (score 4):

No Main Stack Exchange site is designed for or tolerant of discussions.

Instead they are for focused Q&A.

For technical discussions on a Stack Exchange site you could try one of its many Chat Rooms.

However, before you go into a chat room and start discussing your topic, be sure to ask if the room is willing to discuss it.

Comment: And before you go into a chat room and discuss your topic, ask if the room is willing to discuss it.

Comment: @PolyGeo I updated my question description to mention Q&A. the discussion was a typo. I want to know/clarity on where Q&A threads for my product should go.

Comment: SE does not have threads, because it is not a discussion forum. It is a Q&A site with questions and answers that can be referred to collectively as posts.